# How can I determine if a user has ever seen the dialog asking for push notification permission (ios)

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am aware of enabledremotenotificationtypes, but it does not help me because if I receive enabledremotenotificationtypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone, there's no way for me to tell if the user has 1. accepted push notifications once but then turned it off via setting later OR 2. rejected push notifications OR 3. never seen the blue dialog asking for permission.  I need a way to differentiate these three cases.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If you have an iOS developer certificate, please read the changelogs for iOS 6.  I think you will find the answer.

Comment: go to developer.apple.com.  Go to the iOS 6 beta page.  Read the changelogs.  I can't elaborate here, because of the licence agreement.

Comment: how do i make this work for ios 5 or earlier though?

Comment: I can't help you with that, but my suspicion is you can't

Comment: Thanks for being so vague that I have no idea now what you meant back then because there's literally nothing about push notifications in any iOS 6 diff doc that I can find...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a bit of a hack, but it does work. You need to call registerUserNotificationSettings for two different notificationSettings - one without a notificationCategory and one with a notificationCategory:

```
    //Request notification permission
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

//Request notification permission again, but with a category with no actions
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *category = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
category.identifier = @"com.xyz.markNotificationPopupShownCategoryIdentifier";

UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettingsWithCategory = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:[NSSet setWithObject:category]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettingsWithCategory];
```

The didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings method in the app delegate will be called two times, and irrespective of the user's answer in the permission notification, after the second call, the current notification settings will contain the category. As long as the category count is greater than 0, you can know for sure that the notifications permission dialog has been shown:

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].currentUserNotificationSettings.categories.count > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Notifications permissions has been asked");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Notifications permissions hasn't been asked");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is the way I deal with this type of situation--I'm something of a newbie so it's possible this isn't optimal, but it works for me.  Create an `int` property `pushNotificationSeen`.  If the user sees the dialogue and rejects it, set `pushNotificationSeen` to 1.  If the user sees the dialogue and accepts it, set `pushNotificationSeen` to 2.  Then, in the next line of code, call a function like this (defined elsewhere in the code):

```
-(void)saveData
{
if (self.pushNotificationSeen)
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:self.pushNotificationSeen forKey:@"seen?"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
}
```

Then add the following lines to `viewDidLoad`.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.pushNotificationSeen = [defaults integerForKey:@"seen?"];
```

At this point, you can figure out what the user has or hasn't done by checking to see whether self.pushNotificationSeen is 0, 1, or 2.

I hope this is enough information--I'm running on not very much sleep.  If I've been confusing, please let me know and I can clarify.

Comment: The problem is: how to know when the push notification has been seen?

Comment: How do you know if user granted permission?